# Add fieldset with add more button using ajax

Tags: 7

I have one fieldset like,

Education Qualification:
1. School, 2. College, 3. Course, 4. Year (these are the fields which will be in this fieldset)

Now I want to do "Add more" button under this fieldset then it will add same another fieldset as per user's requirement. If anyone have an idea so let me know on this. I can use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) or Content Type also. Which will be suited for this type of form.?

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to achieve with a content type and the [Field collection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection).  With that you can set up a qualification field of type field collection, then go to admin->structure->field collections and add the individual fields (School / College / Course).  If the qualifications field has a "Number of values" setting of "unlinmited" then you'll automatically get the "Add more" functionality as you described.

You may need to also use [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) or [Field Collection Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_fieldset) in order to make the fields appear in a fieldset.

Comment: Thanks Paul for this answer,

Can i do the same with fieldset instead of separate fields?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... you can wrap the fields in a fieldset using Field Group or Field Collection Fieldset as I mentioned.

If you wanted to define a single field type which comprised the sub-fields in a fieldset then you could do that by defining a compound field in code (see http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/compound-fields-in-drupal-7/) but Field Collection basically allows you to do the same thing a lot quicker through the UI.